# Creating a pivot table to apply dynamically to any file name

Tags: excel, vba

Every week I pull the same report for multiple clients and I need to extract a pivot table from it.
I've created a macro that combines full name and auto fills to last row in range. It then creates a pivot table on a new sheet inside the work book. I need this macro to be applicable to whatever the file name is. Thank you so much!

```
Sub Pivot()
'
' Pivot Macro
'

'
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 16.57
    Range("M1").Select
    Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 24.57
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Full Name"
    Range("M2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]&"", ""&RC[-2]"
    Range("M2").Select
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M" & lastrow)
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Cells.Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "American Trans!R1C1:R1048576C31", Version:=7).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=7
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Full Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Pay Total"), "Sum of Pay Total", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Bill Total"), "Sum of Bill Total", xlSum
End Sub
```

Comment: How is it not applicable to whatever the filename is?

Comment: Is "American Trans" the only variable part?

Comment: Where is your macro located? In an normal file, in your personal macro file or in an Add-in?

Comment: It's stored in personal macro. When I try to apply it on another similar report with a different name I get an error. The debugger stops when it gets to ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create